# Should I use custom taxonomies or custom fields for creating a real estate listing site?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a real estate website using Wordpress and I'm in doubt about whether to use custom taxonomies or custom fields for some features. Here is what I'm considering right now:

**property type (Apartment, Office, ...)**: custom taxonomy.

**property status (rent, for sail, ...)**: custom taxonomy.

**property price**: custom filed.

**number of beds, bathrooms and things like these**: custom field.

Could you please tell me am I wrong or right? I have some doubt about **"property status"**. Could I use custom fields for them instead of custom taxonomies?

Consider this situation: a user is looking for an **apartment** (property type) that is **for sale** (property status). Using custom taxonomies for both, make querying faster or using custom taxonomy for property type and custom filed for property status?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend using a custom post type (for the property) with custom taxonomies for type and status, and custom field for price, beds, bathrooms.  Note that there are some EXCELLENT plugins that will accomplish the heavy lifting for you, such as "Custom Field Suite" (best in class), I don't know about specific plugins for taxonomies / post types, but they DO exist, and would make this all MUCH easier for you.

Comment: Thank you so much and yes, I've considered using a custom post type for the property, just didn't mention it here.